# Making a flag with six vertical stripes

Tags: combinatorics

A flag is to be made with six vertical stripes by using colours yellow, blue, green and red in such a way that no two adjacent stripes should have the same colour. In how many ways is this possible? How could I compute this with *Mathematica*?

Comment: Wrong site - you most likely want math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a homework question that has nothing to do with Mathematica.

Comment: I have edited this question to make it acceptable to this site. I did so because I would like it to be reopened. I think Bob Hanlon's answer is worth preserving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been calculated by combinatorial considerations there will be 4*3^5 =972 flags.
This can be done with Mathematica (as small enough for brute force):

```
tu = Tuples[Table[{Yellow, Blue, Green, Red}, {6}]];
dtu = DeleteCases[tu, {___, x_, x_, ___}];
Length@dtu
```

yields 972. (as has been pointed out by eldo **this is essentially as per Bob Hanlon**)

The flags can be visualized:

```
flag[u_] := 
 Graphics[MapThread[{#1, Rectangle[{#2, 0}, {#2 + 1, 4}]} &, {u, 
    Range[6]}]];
GraphicsGrid[Partition[flag /@ dtu, 27], Frame -> All, 
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

[image]

Comment: Where is the difference to Bob Hanlon's answer (except that you show more flags) ?

Comment: @eldo I agree eldo, in retrospect, that I should have read BobHanlon's answer properly and apologize. One minor point of difference is operational...by using the "colors" it facilitates visualization. I am sorry. If you wish I can delete or perhaps more appropriately attribute to Bob Hanlon.

Comment: I would write something like: "Based upon BH's answer ..." :)

Comment: @eldo thank you eldo I have edited to answer (as well as appropriately upvoting Bob Hanlons)

Answer (score 8):

EDITED and CORRECTED to vertical stripes

Allowing that fewer than four colors can be used, then the first stripe can be any of the four colors and each subsequent stripe can be any of the three colors other than the last color used.

```
4*3*3*3*3*3
```

> 972

Alternate approach

```
colors = {yellow, blue, green, red} // Sort;

(flags1 = DeleteCases[Tuples[colors, {6}], {___, x_, x_, ___}]) // Length
```

> 972

```
toColors = Thread[colors -> {Blue, Green, Red, Yellow}];
```

Examples from flags1

```
Partition[
  Graphics[Thread[{flags1[[#]] /. toColors, 
       Table[Rectangle[{n - 1, 0}, {n, 6/GoldenRatio}], {n, 6}]}], 
     ImageSize -> 100] & /@ Range[9], 3] // Grid
```

[image]

If all four colors must be used

```
(flags2 = Select[flags1, Union[#] == colors &]) // Length
```

> 600

Examples from flags2

```
Partition[
  Graphics[Thread[{flags2[[#]] /. toColors, 
       Table[Rectangle[{n - 1, 0}, {n, 6/GoldenRatio}], {n, 6}]}], 
     ImageSize -> 100] & /@ Range[9], 3] // Grid
```

[image]

Comment: I think it should be mentioned that sorting the list of colors is only necessary for finding `flags2`.

Comment: I still don't see any flag though. I want the flag! :p

Comment: Sample flags added.

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that the OP asked for **vertical** stripes.

Comment: @m_goldberg try setting your `$HeadOrientationRelativeToScreen` variable to `-π/2` :)

Comment: @gpap. I did that but the aspect ratio didn't adjust to the new orientation.

Comment: @m_goldberg - corrected orientation.

Comment: @BobHanlon apologies for inadvertently replicating your initial comments...I have +1