# Delete elements from a list with consecutive elements in sublist

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I do not know if this is question has already been asked but I did see some posts on deleting duplicate elements but I am unable to understand completely. So forgive me if this turns out to be duplicate.

I have a list of the form `{{a,b,a,b},{b,a,b,a},{a,a,b,b},{b,b,a,a},{a,b,b,a},{b,a,a,b}}`. I need to eliminate sublist which have same consecutive elements.

Example I should eliminate `{a,a,b,b}`, `{b,b,a,a}`, `{a,b,b,a}` and `{b,a,a,b}` and thus end up with only alternating `a`s and `b`s.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i mean in a loop it is pretty straightforward but I was hoping to avoid loops given the huge number of options in mathematica

Comment: `DeleteCases[lst, {___, x_, x_, ___}]` where *lst* is your target list.

Comment: @ciao Why not make an answer of it?  The key is to explain in detail for newbies how {___, x_, x_, ___} works.

Comment: so does {____,x_,x_,___} work for arrays of arbitrary length ??

Comment: @AbhishekPal Yes it does.  `___` is [`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html) so this will work for a `List` of any length.

Answer (score 8):

As [ciao](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11467/ciao) commented you can use the pattern `{___, x_, x_, ___}`.  This works because `x_` is a *named pattern* and therefore within a pattern expression any match must match every other pattern with the same name.  One could also use `{___, Repeated[x_, {2}], ___}` for the same reason.

```
dat = 
  {{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}, {a, a, b, b}, {b, b, a, a}, {a, b, b, a}, {b, a, a, b}};

dat // DeleteCases[{___, x_, x_, ___}]

dat /. {___, x_, x_, ___} -> Sequence[]

dat // Cases[Except[{___, x_, x_, ___}]]

dat // DeleteCases[{___, Repeated[x_, {2}], ___}]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}}     (* same output for each *)
> ```

Above I use the new-in-v10 operator forms of [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) and [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html).

Reference: [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html), [`Blank`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Blank.html), [`BlankNullSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankNullSequence.html),
[`Repeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html), [`Except`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Except.html)

Other posts I could find where the *uniqueness* of named patterns is used or mentioned:

- [Pattern to match a non-empty list of non-empty lists](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/pattern-to-match-a-non-empty-list-of-non-empty-lists/1277#1277)
- [How to Derive Tuples Without Replacement](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1921/how-to-derive-tuples-without-replacement/7979#7979)
- [Classifying poker hands by pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/classifying-poker-hands-by-pattern-matching/26182#26182)
- [Using MatchQ (or other means) to parse an expression using sums of COS or SIN correctly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/using-matchq-or-other-means-to-parse-an-expression-using-sums-of-cos-or-sin-co/30591#30591)
- [How to get complement of a pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32504/121)
- [Making a flag with six vertical stripes](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51236/121)

---

Because I always like to see another way to accomplish the same task here is a method without any patterns.  I use [`Throw`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Throw.html) and [`Catch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catch.html) to exist [`Fold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) early.

```
test[a_] := Catch[Fold[If[# === #2, Throw[False], #2] &, a]; True]

Select[dat, test]
```

> ```
> {{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}}
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Also

```
lst = {{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}, {a, a, b, b}, {b, b, a, a}, {a, b, b, a}, {b, a, a, b}};

Pick[#, PossibleZeroQ /@ Times @@@ Differences /@ #, False] & @ lst
Pick[#, FreeQ[0|0.] /@ Differences /@ #] & @ lst  (*thanks: Mr.W *)
Pick[#, SequenceCount[#, {Repeated[x_, {2, Infinity}]}]==0&/@#]& @ lst
```

all give

> `{{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard,  of course! (Still on Version 9, I had thought about  `FreeQ[#,0]& /@..` first but settled on `PossibleZeroQ`. The operator form `FreeQ[0]` is much cleaner.

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D

Comment: Caveat with `Differences`:  `{a, b, ∞, ∞}`

Answer (score 5):

With `V 13.1` came `DeleteAdjacentDuplicates`

```
list = {{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}, {a, a, b, b}, {b, b, a, a}, {a, b, b, a}, {b, a, a, b}};

Select[DeleteAdjacentDuplicates /@ list, Length[#] == 4 &]
```

{{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}}

Answer (score 3):

Another way using `Select` and [ConsecutiveQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140472/ordered-subsequences-of-consecutive-integers):

```
ConsecutiveQ = Most[#] == Rest[#] - 1 &; (*By Kuba*)

lst = {{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}, {a, a, b, b}, {b, b, a, a}, {a, b, b, a}, {b, a, a, b}};

Select[lst, AllTrue[Partition[Ordering[#], 2], Not@*ConsecutiveQ] &]

(*{{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}}*)
```

Or using `SubsetCases`:

```
f = SubsetCases[#, {{___, x__, x__, ___}} :> 
    If[Length@{x, x} != Last@Dimensions@#, Nothing, {x, x}]] &;

f@lst

(*{{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Split`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
lst = {{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}, {a, a, b, b}, {b, b, a, a}, {a, b, 
    b, a}, {b, a, a, b}};

Pick[lst, 
 lst // Map[Split[#, SameQ] &] // Map[Length, #, {2}] & // 
  Map[ContainsOnly[{1}]]
 ]
```

**Using `SequenceReplace`:**

```
SequenceReplace[lst, {{___, a_, a_, ___} } :> Nothing]
```

---

*Result*

> {{a, b, a, b}, {b, a, b, a}}